# Selenium ruby check whether webelement is clickable or not?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec, automation

```
def click(tag,prop)
  # wait_for_ajax
  element = wait.until{
  tmp_element = driver.find_element(tag, prop)
  tmp_element if tmp_element.displayed?
  }
 element.click
end
```

This is function to check visibility of element . But I want check click ability of web element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
def click(tag,prop)
  # wait_for_ajax
  element = wait.until{
    tmp_element = driver.find_element(tag, prop)
    tmp_element if tmp_element.enabled? && tmp_element.displayed?
  }
  element.click
end
```